# Can I add a UISearchBar and a UILabel to a UITableView's header on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController`. In the `viewDidLoad` method, I use the code below to set the table view's header. In the `viewDidAppear` method, UI seems to be what I what. But when I click cancel button of the search bar everything disappears.

```
    // header view for table view
    UIView *headView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
    headView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"placeholder";
    self.searchDisplayController_iOS7 = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    [headView addSubview:searchBar];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    label.text = @"label";
    [headView addSubview:label];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headView;
```

Is this the correct way to add both a search bar and label to table view header?

Comment: Nice question... Facing same problem?

Comment: @Shardul I used a trick method to meet this spec. TableView is divided into more sections， cell in section 0 is used to show the label content. In this way, search bar is the only composer in table header view.

Comment: We can use the "Prompt" from UISearchBar